# Assembly Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault

I am trying to take this C code and turn it into Assembly

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int sub(int x, int y) {
    return 2*x+y;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    int a;
    a = atoi(argv[1]);
    return sub(argc,a);
}
```

I used `gcc -S math.c` to turn it into Assembly, and finally understood most of what it's doing. So I rewrote it as this:

```
.globl _main

_sub:
    push %ebp
    mov %esp, %ebp
    mov 0x8(%ebp), %eax         # int x
    mov 0xC(%ebp), %ecx         # int y
    lea (%ecx, %eax, 2), %eax   # 2 * x + y
    pop %ebp
    ret

_main:
    push %ebp
    mov %esp, %ebp
    sub $0x4, %esp              # int a
    mov 0xC(%ebp), %eax
    push 0x4(%eax)              # char*  argv[1]
    call _atoi
    add $0x4, %esp
    push %eax                   # int y
    push 0x8(%ebp)              # int x/argc
    call _sub
    mov %ebp, %esp
    pop %ebp
    ret
```

I am using `gcc -m32 -Wall math.s -o math` to compile it on OS X, and it runs fine. But the line `sub $0x4, %esp` seems very unnecessary to me. So I tried removing it, and it compiles fine. But when I run it using `./math 2` without that line it gives me a `Segmentation fault: 11` error.

I don't see any lines that look like they depend on that line. So I am wondering why does this program need that line, and why is removing it causing that error? Thanks!

Comment: Clearly you didn't write the code if you don't know what it mean. Care to revise your story?

Comment: Well it was generated from gcc and a C script, but then I tried to rewrite from scratch and this is what I got.

Comment: If you are planning to turn this in, your teacher is going to know you didn't write the program yourself since it smells like compiler generated code. You are better off starting from scratch.

Comment: I'm not, I just want to learn Assembly. And I updated the question to explain how I got the code.

Comment: The compiler is playing stack tricks, but it is following this plan. http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/09/06/stack-frame-layout-on-x86-64/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the "sub $4, %esp" line is not related to variable "a"!

The "_atoi" function is using XMM registers so certain variables must be aligned to a 16-byte boundary. To archieve this for local variables on the stack there are two possibilities:

The function called ("_atoi") itself must ensure that the stack is aligned to 16 bytes. This can be done using the following code:

```
push %ebp
mov %esp, %ebp
and $0xFFFFFFF0, %esp # <- This line here
sub $0x1230, %esp
```

This approach is done by 32-bit Windows and Linux programs so your program would work fine on Windows and Linux (I tried that out under Windows)!

Under MacOS X the second possibility is used for 32-bit programs - which is also used on most OSs for 64-bit programs:

When calling a function the stack must already be aligned to 16 bytes.

Your program with the "sub" line:

```
# Here esp is esp_original
call _main      # 4 bytes
push %ebp       # 4 bytes
sub $0x4, %esp  # 4 bytes
push 0x4(%eax)  # 4 bytes
# Here esp must be esp_original+16*N
call _atoi
```

If you remove the "sub" instruction or you replace it by a "sub $8, %esp" instruction then the stack is no longer aligned. If you require 8 more bytes of stack you have to do a "sub $20, %esp" and not a "sub $4, %esp" because of that.

Sadly this requirement makes assembly programming more difficult - especially for beginners - on MacOS X.